# objective-C. Arc library in non-arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release, retain

I added PESGraph arc library to a project without arc.

I have already found an answer that it is possible and it really works. But how to handle memory for objects from arc library in non-arc project. I mean at least alloc, retain, release.

For example can I write release in dealloc method for object from arc if it was declared as retain property?

Comment: ARC doesn't take over your objects. If you write non-ARC code, then you still have to manually manage memory (well, you have to do that with ARC too, sometimes...). If you got an object returned by an ARC library, you still need to retain and release it inside your non-ARC code.

Comment: @H2CO3 You should post that as an answer. I don't want to steal your rep by essentially repeating your comment.

Comment: @JustSid It's not worth it :) Rob Mayoff has already provided an excellent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file is compiled with ARC disabled, you can call `release` (and `retain` and `autorelease`) in that file, and you are responsible for making those calls in the proper places.

The idea of ARC is that, when ARC is enabled, the compiler inserts those calls for you.  If you have ARC disabled for some of your files, then in those files you must insert the calls yourself.

Cocoa has very strong conventions for when you need to `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` objects if ARC is disabled.  Read [*Cocoa Core Competencies: Memory Management*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html) to get started.  Then look at the [*Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) if you need more details.  It's not really very advanced.

The compiler follows the same conventions when ARC is enabled.  That is why you can link ARC-enabled files and ARC-disabled files in the same executable.

Comment: thanks, in my case arc seems to be enabled and disabled at once.

Answer (score 0):

Memory management in Cocoa is completely local -- what memory management operations need to be performed in a function can be determined purely by looking at that function only, without caring about other code. Each function can be considered independently in terms of memory management, as long as they all follow the rules. ARC simply implements the rules (the same ones you would follow in MRC) automatically. Different parts of the code can use ARC or MRC independently, without affecting each other.